# How to identify an element by classname containing curly brackets

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver-io

when i try to access element:

```
browser.element('.object{ media }');
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error: Argument was an invalid selector (e.g. XPath/CSS).
  at element(".object{ media }") - index.js:312:3
```

Is it possible to access elements by class name including curly brackets?

Comment: Do you mean that class name value contains curly bracets? Can you share source code sample for the same?

Answer (score 2):

As per your question and your *code trials* to access desired element with classname containing *curly brackets* i.e. `{}` you can use the following solution:

- `XPath`:

  ```
  "//*[@class=\"object{ media }\"]"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Following what @DebanjanB said,

You can use something called Regular Expressions to sort issues like this out, what Debanjan has shown you is known as this.

[Regular Expressions Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

It would be useful if you read through a guide so you fully understand the code you are putting into your project, this will allow you to make better use of it later on in your testing.

All the best,

Jack